# MBProgressHUD while processing data from array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, background-process, mbprogresshud

I want to use MBProgressHUD to inform user about processing data from an array. I've got an array with N elements and for each element I have to process it (which implies some time), so I would like to inform the user with the progress (x% completed)

I have a method which process this array (**processData:(NSArray *)data**) iterating over every element of the array

I tried to set hud detail text label to 0% before calling **processData:(NSArray *)data** and then call this method and update the hud in every iteration but hud is not updated (I think that it's due to I'm executing the method in the main thread...)

There is a way of doing this? I should execute **processData:(NSArray *)data** in background? If this is the solution, how can I do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: mind sharing some code ??

Comment: you should update it from main thread. Any UI activity should always go in main thread

Comment: you are probably not using MBProgressHUd the right way.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the app responsive you should execute any long running code in a separate thread. To do so, just move the entire logic of the method `processData` inside a block like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    /// The code here will be executed in a background thread
});
```

And to update the UI, you should make sure to make the proper calls from the main UI thread.
So, you can now execute the proper code inside another block that will be executed in the main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    /// The code here will be executed in main UI thread
});
```